# C wrapper around C++ library without unnecessary header files

Tags: c++

C++ newbie here. I'm creating a C wrapper around C++ library which expose just `foo()` function.

*wrapper.h*

```
#include "SomeLibrary.h"
#include "SomeAnotherLibrary.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
  void foo();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

*wrapper.cpp*

```
#include "wrapper.h"

void foo() {
  // calls to `SomeLibrary.h` and `SomeAnotherLibrary.h` functions...
}
```

I would like to compile this code just to be able to call `foo()` from a different C code. Note that I care just about the `foo()` function. I would like to completely ignore `SomeLibrary.h` and `SomeAnotherLibrary.h` header files.

So I tried to compilethe wrapper into object file `wrapper.o` as follows:

```
g++ -c wrapper.cpp -o wrapper.o -I../some_library/include -I../some_other_library/include -L../some_library/lib -lSomeFirstLibrary -lSomeSecondLibrary
```

**Problem**:

When I used `wrapper.o` in my C project, it still require me to load bunch of header files from `SomeLibrary.h` and `SomeAnotherLibrary.h` (which I do not care about at all). Here is my C project code:

*my_project.c*:

```
#include "wrapper.h"

void main() {
  foo();
}
```

And compile it:

```
gcc my_project.c wrapper.o -o my_project
```

Which yields following error:

```
my_program.c:3:28: fatal error: SomeLibrary.h: No such file or directory
```

**Question**:

How I should compile the wrapper to ignore all other header files except `wrapper.h`?

Comment: A side note: use `ìnt main` instead of `void main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
#include "SomeLibrary.h"
#include "SomeAnotherLibrary.h"
```

from `wrapper.h` and put those lines in `wrapper.cpp` next to `#include "wrapper.h"`.

Then remove the `-L../some_library/lib -lSomeFirstLibrary -lSomeSecondLibrary` linker related flags from the

```
g++ -c wrapper.cpp -o wrapper.o -I../some_library/include -I../some_other_library/include
```

command (`-c` means no linking is done here so there's no point in passing linker flags)

and move it to the

```
gcc my_project.c wrapper.o -o my_project -L../some_library/lib -lSomeFirstLibrary -lSomeSecondLibrary
```

command like this.

Then it should work.

Comment: It removed the missing header error. However, now I get many `undefined reference to` messages.

Comment: That's progress though cuz now things compile and the error's now in the linker. Adding `-L../some_library/lib -lSomeFirstLibrary -lSomeSecondLibrary
` should fix the problem (these also shouldn't need to be in the `g++ -c wrapper.cpp  ...` command as that one doesn't do any linking).

Comment: @user1518183 Nemáš za co.

Answer (score 1):

When you get `undefined reference to...` messages, it means that you are declaring functions, and calling them, but never defining them. The error is coming from the fact that you are linking your libraries in the wrong place. You do not need to link libraries to the `.o` file, you need to link them to the executable file.